# UI field for text and picture editing

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

I have a CreateView with title, content and image fields.

[image]

I would like to allow users to put the picture where they please within the contend field. I would like to add to my site a field like this :

[image]

I don't need something so detailed but for the moment the picture position is where I have put the img html tag. And I want it to be chosen by the user as he is writing a post.
If someone could help me please to figure out how to achieve this with bootstrap and django. thx

Answer (score 0):

So I need to integrate a custom rich text editor and this is how you [do it](https://www.codementor.io/hiteshgarg14/how-to-integrate-custom-rich-text-editor-in-django-54czmp0gi)